# Why was Yoda chosen to learn to become a Force spirit?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In The Clone Wars season 6, Qui-Gon Jinn told Yoda that he was chosen to learn how to retain his consciousness after death. He was brought to the Force Priestesses to pass the trials before his training could begin. There, when the Priestesses were debating among themselves why he should be trained, Serenity mentioned that "his destiny was already set, it is not for us to decide...He is to teach one who has to save the universe from a great imbalance. For this, the great gift will be his".

I assume that this is in reference to his future role in training Luke Skywalker to become a Jedi, so that Luke may play his part in the defeat of the Sith, thus bringing the Force back into balance. I would also assume that the "gift" of consciousness after death was granted to enable Yoda to fulfil his destiny, not merely as a reward for success. Promising Yoda with greater power would be counter-intuitive of the Force, since that is the way of the dark side, the entity in question that the Force is trying to bring into balance here. It would also have been unnecessary for setting Yoda down this path - something like a vision would have sufficed.

Based on those assumptions then, why is the ability to retain consciousness after death necessary? When Luke returned to Yoda before his death, Yoda told him "No more training do you require." So I assume Yoda wouldn't appear before Luke after dying to give further training, in the maximum possible span of a few months between his death and the Battle of Endor. I doubt Yoda was taught this ability just so he could pass it on to Obi-Wan, the one person who actively used his retained consciousness to guide Luke. This reason sounds too roundabout to me, not to mention that it was Qui-Gon, not Yoda, who trained Obi-Wan during his exile. If Obi-Wan was the intended beneficiary, and he was strong enough in the Force to communicate with Qui-Gon during his exile, including Yoda in this is completely superfluous.

So, exactly how was the gift of retaining consciousness after death intended to serve Yoda's destiny of training one to save the universe from this great imbalance? Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely, and Yoda's destiny spoken of by the Force Priestesses is to make a comeback in Episodes VII-IX, a time when there are still new Jedi to be trained and when Yoda is well and truly dead?

Comment: No one knew when Yoda was going to die. It sure would suck if he died before Luke was trained. But if Yoda can come back as a Force Ghost, he can help finish the training.

Comment: Maybe the Priestesses just wanted to be sure? Predictions of the future don't always pan out as expected. Just look at the "Chosen One" prophesy.

Comment: Uh. Luke wasn't the one who brought the balance to the Force. Anakin was.

Comment: "Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe..." ~George Lucas. Short story: Anakin kills the emperor, Balance restored.

Comment: I like how you referred to the dark side as an entity. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 6):

We have limited information on the [Force Priestesses](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Priestesses), most if not all coming from Season 6 of The Clone Wars.

To answer the question in title, [Yoda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda) was chosen because:

> "He is to teach one who has to save the universe from a great imbalance."

For that, the Priestesses decided to grant him the gift of knowledge of becoming a force spirit.

**"Promising Yoda with greater power would be counter-intuitive of the Force, since that is the way of the dark side, the entity in question that the Force is trying to bring into balance here." - OP**

Power itself is not the way of the Dark Side. Neither is the promise of Power. It is the *quest* for power that corrupts. Remember that Yoda is quickly approaching 900 at this point in time (877 if my math is correct). He has been a Jedi Master for something like 800 years, and was the Grandmaster of the Order several times. He is probably the least corruptible being in the entire galaxy.

In addition to that, this was not a "promise of power". It was a gift. Yoda's destiny was set, he *would* train Luke. As almost a way of saying "thank you for playing this major role in restoring balance to the force" they *gifted* him the knowledge to become a force ghost when he died.

The gift had little to do with the role itself. I suppose it could have been a backup plan to ensure their future they saw came to be (in case of  death, break glass, become a ghost, train Luke anyway).

So in short, Yoda was chosen because the Priestesses wanted to both ensure the future, and thank Yoda.

> "He is to teach one who has to save the universe from a great imbalance. For this [service], the great gift will be his" - Serenity

Answer (score 2):

**There were no other Jedi worthy of training except him and Kenobi.**

Yoda is far from perfect - he makes a lot of mistakes in Clone War, he doesn't see Sidious in front of his very eyes - yet, he is the best the Jedi have, the wisest and most powerful in the Force. He was also very close to Qui-Gon Jinn and this personal connection is required to communicate with him.

As for rest of Jedi Masters, Kenobi is also very wise, although he is not that powerful. He also has a personal connection with Qui-Gon Jinn. Windu is perhaps more powerful than Kenobi, but he is too attached to the doomed Republic. The rest of them are well ... chaff in the wind ... they do not stand a chance against the Sith.

Note that Force Priestesses have the ability to foresee the future, and that they probably discerned that Luke would need two living teachers (as Kenobi would die on Death Star 1) while his connection with Force was still too weak to communicate with Force Ghosts. But they also perceived that in the latter part of his life, Force Ghosts of both Kenobi and Yoda would be useful to him. Luke still didn't know many Jedi teachings when Palpatine died on Death Star 2. Also, the ability to become a Force Ghost was described by Yoda as "victory for all times." With this ability, the Jedi Order could never be totally destroyed, as Force Ghosts would find a way to intervene in the physical world .

Finally, out-of-universe, there were only two "older" Jedi in original trilogy, Yoda and Obi-Wan. Both of them became Force Ghosts, so naturally they had to be chosen for training before that.